# Using Docker Compose to connect to mysql running in another container

Tags: java, mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker and docker-compose.

I have mysql running in a docker container, with two databases initialized.

I can connect to it using:

```
mysql --port=3306 -h192.0.0.1 -uroot -ppassword
```

When I run:

```
docker ps

04bc1d308484        container-mysql   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          3306/tcp            container-mysql
```

My query is that now I want to connect to it from another container using

```
docker-compose up.

another-image:
  image: another-image
  command: /opt/start.sh
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  environment:
    DB_URL: container-mysql
    DB_USER: root
    DB_PASSWORD: password
  external_links:
    - container-mysql
```

Can someone please guide me whats missing and what else is needed.

My container-mysql has two database schema's.

Example:
firstdb
seconddb

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question! but always consider checking existing open source projects who have done this before, read the code and debug.. I advise checking this `docker-compose.yml` file https://github.com/LaraDock/laradock/blob/master/docker-compose.yml Also check the DB container and it's base image to get a full overview of what's going on and how it's working. Best.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer to it. In case anyone else comes across the same problem, just do

```
docker network ls
```

This command lists all the docker networks.

| NETWORK ID    | NAME            | DRIVER   | SCOPE    |
| ------------- | --------------- | -------- | -------- |
| c24bee6b5b8e  | network-mysql | bridge   | local    |

Thus, a compose file demonstrating this might look like the following:

```
another-image:
  image: another-image
  command: /opt/start.sh
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  environment:
    DB_URL: container-mysql
    DB_USER: root
    DB_PASSWORD: password
  external_links:
    - container-mysql
  network_mode: network-mysql
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `network_mode: network-mysql` in latest version. Use `networks:`