# Share mysql container in different docker compose files in different networks

Tags: docker-compose

I have two docker compose file in different networks. One of the docker compose file contains mysql container, which is already running.
Now, i have second docker compose file which is in different network. In this docker compose file, i want to use same mysql container as in first docker container as one of the container depends on mysql.
Thought here is, I dont want to create 2 mysql containers.

docker compose 1:

```
  services:
   
       mysql:
      
          restart: always

          container_name: container_name

          image: mysql

          environment:
           ....
           ....
          volumes:
            - .....
          healthcheck:
            - ...
          networks:
            - some-network
```

Docker compose 2:

```
service1:

  container_name: service1
  restart: always
  build:
    context: .......
  volumes:
     - ......
  ports:
     - .....
  networks:
     - some-network-1
  depends_on:
    - mysql from docker compose1
```

How this can be achieved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Docker Compose to connect to mysql running in another container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470411/using-docker-compose-to-connect-to-mysql-running-in-another-container)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
external_links:
    - container-mysql
```

instead of

```
depends_on:
    - mysql from docker compose1
```